# How to use "Random Variable" in JSON Extractor in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am capturing bunch of available seat list using JSON Extractor (Please refer "1_JSON_Extractor" ) , I am using -1 to capture all the ordinals, it is working fine (Refer "2_Debug_Sampler").

I need to take the random value from the list, Instead of using 0 for Random Ordinal, I am trying to use Random Variable here,( Please refer "3_Random_variable"). But it is not working fine.

I am planning to use the the Random variable "C_Seat_1" in the place of JSON Extractor Match No and get the random value. (Please refer "4_Json_Extractor")[1_JSON_Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quSw9.png) .[2_Debug_Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjhLW.png)[3_Random_variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM9IL.png)[4_Json_Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qjeg.png)

Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

> **0.  Configuration elements**
>
> 1. Pre-Processors
> 2. Timers
> 3. Sampler
> 4. **Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)**
> 5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

- [Random Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable) is a Configuration Element
- [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) is a Post-Processor

Hence when Random Variable is evaluated JSON Extractor hasn't been executed yet therefore `${C_Selected_Seat_All_matchNr}` is not defined

You can just go for [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) functions combination to pick a random seat directly where required without any extra configuratino elements, something like:

```
 ${__V(C_Selected_Seat_All_${__Random(1,${C_Selected_Seat_All_matchNr},)},)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Dmitri, Shall I use the random function straightway in the JSON extractor ? Or I need to use -1 as Match No and get all the _matchNr value and then I need to use the JSON extractor ?

Please find the attached images for reference, But it is not working for me, "C_SelectedSeat" is not getting captured. Can you please check and correct me 

[![GetAllSeat][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEcsw.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zuRU.png